# correlations between factors in r- scores or loadings?

Tags: r, cross-correlation, factor-analysis

I've conducted a factor analysis in r with three factors (function=fa {psych};rotation=promax ; method=GLS).

```
       fa1=fa(d,nfactors=3,rotate="promax",oblique.scores=TRUE,method="gls",missing=TRUE,scores=TRUE,impute="mean")
```

Now I would like to add a correlation matrix between the three factors.
Which matrix will be better in defining the correlation between the factors?
using the scores correlation?

```
    cor(fa1$scores)
```

or the loadings correlation?

```
    cor(fa1$loadings)
```